# Javascript addition weird result

Tags: javascript

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R6kMA/2/) simple animation, the result of the addition in line 56:

```
this.elapsedTime += dt;
```

of the JS script is something like -1378499284830.2598 for no particular reason.
In fact the numbers that I'm adding are two "normal" numbers.

**UPDATE:**

And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R6kMA/6/) is the revision that worked.

Comment: May you tell me, what an `console.log(this.elapsedTime, dt);` on line 55 returns? I am somehow unable to get to this line..

Comment: It starts with something like "0 46.55839918339552" and continues with something like "-1378500454682.2834 46.55839918339552"

Comment: You can clearly see the numbers are not what you are expecting http://jsfiddle.net/R6kMA/4/

Comment: So we know now, the problem isn't the addition. Because `this.elapsedTime` somehow is getting negative.

Comment: then you need to find out how the second value got there.

Comment: But it's clear from the first addition that the numbers are simple "0 46.55839918339552" and the result is negative. How is this happening?

Comment: @Zosimas the negative value is not the result of the addition. Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Oh sorry, then the timestamp returns a weird number only the first time?

Comment: @Zosimas the first dt is 0, then it becomes negative trillion, so each addition, you are adding negative trillion, of course your end result is going to be a negative number. Look at the fiddle I posted

Comment: Ok, now can someone please explain this behaviour: [jsfiddle.net/R6kMA/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/R6kMA/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is not in the addition, but on line 86:

```
var dt = timestamp - last_frame_update_time;
frame = coin_animation.update(dt);
```

There, in the first call you obtain the negative value you are trying to add later. I'd  recommend debugging that using something like chrome dev tools.

EDIT: You are trying to do an operation between two values that have nothing to do between themselves. 
timestamp is the parameter received from requestAnimationFrame ([check the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame#Parameters)), and the other one is `new Date().getTime();` which is not appropriate.

Try changing line 96 to:

```
 last_frame_update_time = 0;
```

Comment: by the way, shouldn't `frame` be `var frame`?

Comment: The last_frame_update_time has allready a value from "last_frame_update_time = new Date().getTime();". So the timestamp doesn't return a right value the first time???

Comment: the last_frame_update_time is returning the trillion large number, the timestamp is below 1000 so the negative it produced

Comment: that time is returned in milliseconds if I am not mistaking. Here look at this, it explains a lot http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp the get time will give you something that's larger than 1378501286912

Comment: Check the edit I've just made to this answer. Basically it's what @Huangism was pointing

Comment: Thank you @Huangism, I set `last_frame_update_time = 0` at the beggining and everyhting worked.

Comment: @Huangism Please don't link to w3schools. It's a terrible resource. Use MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). It's more detailed, the examples are formatted much better (and are more useful), and unlike w3schools it contains no errors or horrible advice. W3Schools even propagates the use of `eval` as a primary way to parse JSON!